# Problem installing TensorFlow for Visual Studio Code C++ project in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Virtual Machine

Tags: c++, tensorflow, installation, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I am doing a capstone project for the Udacity C++ online course.  I had a choice between adding features to a snake computer game or creating my own project.  I am looking for a job in artificial intelligence so I decided to create my own project and use TensorFlow to do a convolutional neural network for a cat dog image classifier in Visual Studio Code.  I am getting errors during TensorFlow installation and I don't know how to get #include path working for TensorFlow op.h and shape_inference.h.

Here is the GitHub project link: https://github.com/ProfHariSeldon/CppND-Capstone-Hello-World

I tried installing TensorFlow in my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Virtual Machine using the instructions in https://www.tensorflow.org/install:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow
```

I'm not sure how to use TensorFlow in C++ (I took a Udemy.com course (https://www.udemy.com/course/machinelearning/) that used TensorFlow in Python not C++) because the only mention of doing that says it needs to be done in Windows? Is that right?

TensorFlow is tested and supported on the following 64-bit systems:

- Python 3.5–3.8
- Ubuntu 16.04 or later
- Windows 7 or later (with C++ redistributable)
- macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (no GPU support)
- Raspbian 9.0 or later
  https://www.tensorflow.org/install

The two problems seem to be:

### First

The #includes recommended by the Udacity C++ course using this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
```

The actual location of those two files in my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Virtual Machine

```
#include "./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/include/tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
```

Neither #include works both say "cannot open source file" in Visual Studio Code

### Second

During install I got these errors:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 has requirement setuptools>=41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.0.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: google-auth 1.18.0 has requirement setuptools>=40.3.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.0.1 which is incompatible.
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py2 and f2py2.7 are installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts pyrsa-decrypt, pyrsa-encrypt, pyrsa-keygen, pyrsa-priv2pub, pyrsa-sign and pyrsa-verify are installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script chardetect is installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script google-oauthlib-tool is installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script markdown_py is installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script tensorboard is installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts estimator_ckpt_converter, saved_model_cli, tensorboard, tf_upgrade_v2, tflite_convert, toco and toco_from_protos are installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

The full install text output is in the GitHub project README (https://github.com/ProfHariSeldon/CppND-Capstone-Hello-World/blob/master/README.md) because the forum won't let me put it in this post because it "looks like spam"

### UPDATE

EDIT: I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 (as suggested below) and that got rid of the two ERRORs, but the WARNINGs are still there. I still can't get #include to work is there anything I'm missing with #include?

```
  WARNING: The scripts pyrsa-decrypt, pyrsa-encrypt, pyrsa-keygen, pyrsa-priv2pub, pyrsa-sign and pyrsa-verify are installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script markdown_py is installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script google-oauthlib-tool is installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.8 are installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script tensorboard is installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts estimator_ckpt_converter, saved_model_cli, tensorboard, tf_upgrade_v2, tflite_convert, toco and toco_from_protos are installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I noticed that this guide: https://medium.com/createdd-notes/install-tensorflow-with-virtuelenv-and-visual-studio-code-on-mac-6b9f93f0fb08
On how to install TensorFlow in Visual Studio Code says:
"Set up Visual Studio Code
Install the Visual Studio Python Extension" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

I will try that tomorrow, but I don't know if that would fix it because the whole point of this project is to do a TensorFlow C++ project not a Python project.

Comment: ***google-auth 1.18.0 has requirement setuptools>=40.3.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.0.1 which is incompatible.*** Looks like something you can investigate. If there is not an update in apt for this package maybe you want to get an older version of TensorFlow

Comment: A second option may be to ugrade ubuntu to 20.04

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 has setuptools-45.2.0-1: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-setuptools but 18.04 has only 39.0.1-2

Comment: I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and that got rid of the two ERRORs, but the WARNINGs are still there.  I still can't get #include to work is there anything I'm missing with #include?

Comment: I don't really know what is causing that. It is an unusual path however. I think someone else will have to help with this problem.

Comment: I noticed that this guide https://medium.com/createdd-notes/install-tensorflow-with-virtuelenv-and-visual-studio-code-on-mac-6b9f93f0fb08
 on how to install TensorFlow in Visual Studio Code says:
"Set up Visual Studio Code
Install the Visual Studio Python Extension" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

I will try that tomorrow, but I don't know if that would fix it because the whole point of this project is to do a TensorFlow C++ project not a Python project.

Comment: I don't think it is involved at this point of the process but I could be wrong.

Comment: I found out that all this TensorFlow for Python is not what I need. I finally found out how to install TensorFlow for C++ (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) it's not on their main webpage (https://www.tensorflow.org/install)

Comment: I resolved this issue I untared the C++ Tensorflow install file using Archive Manager not "sudo tar -C /usr/local/ -xzf libtensorflow-gpu-linux-x86_64-1.15.0.tar.gz" my mistake
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41506

Thank you for telling me to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04