# Test if TensorFlow installation has worked failed on Python 3.8.2 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I tried installing TensorFlow in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Virtual Machine using the instructions in https://www.tensorflow.org/install:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow
```

I got a few WARNINGs so I want to check if TensorFlow can run:

```
WARNING: The scripts pyrsa-decrypt, pyrsa-encrypt, pyrsa-keygen, pyrsa-priv2pub, pyrsa-sign and pyrsa-verify are installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script markdown_py is installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script google-oauthlib-tool is installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.8 are installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script tensorboard is installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts estimator_ckpt_converter, saved_model_cli, tensorboard, tf_upgrade_v2, tflite_convert, toco and toco_from_protos are installed in '/home/tlroot/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I found code from these three links that is used to test if TensorFlow is working:

https://medium.com/createdd-notes/install-tensorflow-with-virtuelenv-and-visual-studio-code-on-mac-6b9f93f0fb08

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/deep-learning-with/9781786469786/3bdee8f3-ca88-438a-8141-42d2a12db71d.xhtml

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34658

This is the code that I ran to test and I get an error on the last line of code "print sess.run(hello)" and "print(sess.run(hello))" also got an error:

```
tlroot@tlroot-VirtualBox:~$ python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant("Hello TensorFlow!")
2020-07-15 11:06:33.171630: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-07-15 11:06:33.171702: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-07-15 11:06:33.171728: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (tlroot-VirtualBox): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-07-15 11:06:33.172012: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-07-15 11:06:33.183668: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 2591995000 Hz
2020-07-15 11:06:33.183782: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f574c000b60 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-15 11:06:33.183800: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
>>> hello = tf.constant("Hello TensorFlow!")
>>> sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
>>> print sess.run(hello)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print sess.run(hello)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tlroot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 957, in run
    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
  File "/home/tlroot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1106, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
>>>
```

This question is a continuation of my questions about installing TensorFlow that I posted here: [Problem installing TensorFlow for Visual Studio Code C++ project in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882248/problem-installing-tensorflow-for-visual-studio-code-c-project-in-ubuntu-18-04)

### Update

I tried "print(sess.run(hello))" and that didn't work either.

```
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tlroot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 957, in run
    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
  File "/home/tlroot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1106, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
>>>
```

I tried python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))" and that didn't work either.

````
tlroot@tlroot-VirtualBox:~$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
2020-07-15 12:38:47.446234: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-07-15 12:38:47.446361: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-07-15 12:38:47.446423: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (tlroot-VirtualBox): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-07-15 12:38:47.446723: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-07-15 12:38:47.462856: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 2591995000 Hz
2020-07-15 12:38:47.463198: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7ff1c0000b60 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-15 12:38:47.463294: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
tf.Tensor(885.7727, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tlroot@tlroot-VirtualBox:~$```
````

Comment: Try `print(sess.run(hello))`

Comment: I tried "print(sess.run(hello))" and that didn't work either. RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty. Add operations to the graph before calling run().

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements), Tensorflow requires Python 3.5 to 3.7, I don't think 3.8.2 is supported. But anyway I'd add parenthesis to the `print` statement, as this is required on Python 3.x

Comment: I tried "print(sess.run(hello))" and that didn't work either.  RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().

Comment: If you're trying to test your installation, you could just run something like this `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"`

Comment: That didn't work either (see Update on my original post) it looks like something went wrong with the TensorFlow installation.  I guess I should add all of those WARNINGs to my path.

Comment: My guess is it probably went wrong because of unsupported python version

Comment: I found out that all this TensorFlow for Python is not what I need.  I finally found out how to install TensorFlow for C++ (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) it's not on their main webpage (https://www.tensorflow.org/install)

Comment: I resolved this issue I untared the C++ Tensorflow install file using Archive Manager not "sudo tar -C /usr/local/ -xzf libtensorflow-gpu-linux-x86_64-1.15.0.tar.gz" my mistake
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41506